# Why does the element with lower zindex value appear on top of element with higher z-index using css?

Tags: html, css

i have popup_overlay element with higher zindex appearing below the left_control_wrapper and right_control_wrapper elements with low zindex value.

below is my code,

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.controls_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left_control_wrapper,
.right_control_wrapper {
  /*elements with low zindex and appearing above 
   popup_overlay */
  display: flex;
  z-index: 4;
}

.content_wrapper {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.popup_overlay {
  /*element appearing below left_control_wrapper and right_control_wrapper*/
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="controls_wrapper">
    <div class="left_control_wrapper"> <!-- element with lower zindex and appears above //popup_overlay -->
      <button>add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right_control_wrapper"> <!-- //element with lower zindex and appears above //popup_overlay //dropdown menu -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <button>popup</button>
          <div class="popup_overlay"> <!-- //this is the element with higher z-index -->
            <div class="popup_dialog>some content</div>
                            <div class=" popup_notification>something</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the left_control_wrapper and right_control_wrapper to appear below the popup_overlay. how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that the

```
.content_wrapper {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

The Content Wrapper which holds the PopUp has a lower Z index than the left and right control Wrapper. As the Pop up is wrapped by the content-wrapper Division It is displayed below the others.

So increase this content wrapper's z-index and It should work as you want.

Comment: thanks but increasing this z-index would make the right_control_wrapper (which is a menu list) to be below the card div. i want the right_control-wrapper to be above the card and when this popup overlay is visible then right_control_wrapper should be below the popup_overlay.